# The 'componentDidMount' lifecycle method does not update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, render

I have a component called DiscardPile that's receive in your props (props.cards) an array of objects like this:

```
{key: 'key', 'type', suit: 'suit', label: 'label', flipped: 'fliped, draggable: 'draggable', currentOrder: 0}
```

Well, the component DiscardPile is shown bellow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/core';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/droppable';

import './DiscardPile.scss';

import Card from '../Card/Card';
export default class DiscardPile extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentCards: []        
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let currentCards = [...this.props.cards];
        for(let i = 0; i < currentCards.length; i++) {
            currentCards[i].currentOrder = i;
        }
        this.setState({currentCards: currentCards});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="discard-pile" className="discard-pile">
                {this.state.currentCards.map(card =>(
                    <Card key={card.key} type={card.type} suit={card.suit} label={card.label} flipped={card.flipped} draggable={card.draggable} currentOrder={card.currentOrder}></Card>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

The 'componentDidMount' should update the currentOrder attribute of the object and render the cards list again, but this is not happening. In fact, the list being rendered empty.
What could I do to fix this?

(Sorry for my bad english)

--**UPDATE**--

The DiscardPile component is called by the KlondikeTable component, shown bellow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './KlondikeTable.scss';

import Card from './../../generalComponents/Card/Card';
import DiscardPile from '../../generalComponents/DiscardPile/DiscardPile';
import FlippedPile from '../../generalComponents/FlippedPile/FlippedPile';
import SuitsPile from '../../generalComponents/SuitsPile/SuitsPile';
import CardsColumn from '../../generalComponents/CardsColumn/CardsColumn';

export default class KlondikeTable extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cards: [],
            initialDistribution: {
                discardPile: [],
                flippedPile: [],
                cardsPile1: [],
                cardsPile2: [],
                cardsPile3: [],
                cardsPile4: [],
                cardsPile5: [],
                cardsPile6: [],
                cardsPile7: [],
            },
            currentDistribution: null
        }
        this.generateCards = this.generateCards.bind(this);
        this.shuffleCards = this.shuffleCards.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.generateCards();
    }

    generateCards() {
        let cards = [];
        let types = ["K","Q","J","10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","A"];
        let suits = ["spades", "clubs", "diamonds", "hearts"];
        for(let i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
            for(let j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                cards.push(
                    {key: types[j] + "-" + suits[i] + "-0", type: types[j], suit: suits[i], label: "0", flipped: false, draggable: true, currentOrder: 0}
                )
            }
        }
        this.setState(state => ({...state, cards: cards}), () => {
            this.shuffleCards();
        });
    }

    shuffleCards() {
        let amount = 52;
        let numbersArray = [];
        let cards = [...this.state.cards];
        let initialDistribution = {...this.state.initialDistribution};
        for(let i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            numbersArray.push(i);
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount);
            let removedElement = cards.splice(randomNumber, 1)[0];
            initialDistribution.discardPile.push(removedElement);
            amount--;
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
            let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * amount);
            let removedElement = cards.splice(randomNumber, 1)[0];
            if(i < 1) {
                initialDistribution.cardsPile1.push(removedElement);
            }else if(i < 3) {
                initialDistribution.cardsPile2.push(removedElement);
            }else if(i < 6) {
                initialDistribution.cardsPile3.push(removedElement);
            }else if(i < 10) {
                initialDistribution.cardsPile4.push(removedElement);
            }else if(i < 15) {
                initialDistribution.cardsPile5.push(removedElement);
            }else if(i < 21) {
                initialDistribution.cardsPile6.push(removedElement);
            }else if(i >= 21) {
                initialDistribution.cardsPile7.push(removedElement);
            }
            amount--;
        }
        this.setState({initialDistribution: initialDistribution, currentDistribution: initialDistribution});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="klondike-table">
                <DiscardPile cards={this.state.initialDistribution.discardPile}></DiscardPile>
                <FlippedPile cards={this.state.initialDistribution.flippedPile}></FlippedPile>
                <div className="suits-piles-container">
                    <SuitsPile></SuitsPile>
                    <SuitsPile></SuitsPile>
                    <SuitsPile></SuitsPile>
                    <SuitsPile></SuitsPile>
                </div>
                <CardsColumn cards={this.state.initialDistribution.cardsPile1}></CardsColumn>
                <CardsColumn cards={this.state.initialDistribution.cardsPile2}></CardsColumn>
                <CardsColumn cards={this.state.initialDistribution.cardsPile3}></CardsColumn>
                <CardsColumn cards={this.state.initialDistribution.cardsPile4}></CardsColumn>
                <CardsColumn cards={this.state.initialDistribution.cardsPile5}></CardsColumn>
                <CardsColumn cards={this.state.initialDistribution.cardsPile6}></CardsColumn>
                <CardsColumn cards={this.state.initialDistribution.cardsPile7}></CardsColumn>                
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: @Dexygen completely irrelevant here.

Comment: Are you sure that `this.props.cards` always have a length > 0? What do you get if you add to componentDidMount `console.log(this.props.cards.length)`?

Comment: Either you haven't included it in your post, or you have forgotten to define the interface definition for your state.

Comment: @Chris, please, check the update. I put the console log and i'ts showed 0. Is it because in the KlondikeComponent i define the array in componentDidMount (called after the render)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to have a currentCards state element. Think of it this way if you need your state element to be always updated with your props element content you might be thinking it wrong. Moreover, if your state element is just going to be a slight variation of the element you are receiving in props then you definitely don't need it.
Your code isn't working because on the first render your component is receiving an empty array, thus setting an empty currentCards array and never changing it.

Just use

```
render() {
    return (
        <div id="discard-pile" className="discard-pile">
            {this.props.cards.map((card, currentOrder)=>(
                <Card key={card.key} type={card.type} suit={card.suit} label={card.label} flipped={card.flipped} draggable={card.draggable} currentOrder={currentOrder}></Card>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}`
```

to achieve the expected behavior.

If what you want is to have only the initial version of props.cards on your state you might want to use componentDidUpdate or even shouldComponentUpdate with a well defined set of rules to avoid performance damage or infinitely re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Since `componentDidMount` only runs once, any changes you're making will not take effect if the `prop` changes later on.

The prop `cards` is initially set to `[]`. So unless you move your ordering logic somewhere else, it will never be updated in state to contain your updated array.

Without knowing the exact logic you want, something like this may work:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.cards.length !== this.props.cards.length) {
    let currentCards = [...this.props.cards];
    for(let i = 0; i < currentCards.length; i++) {
      currentCards[i].currentOrder = i;
    }
    this.setState({currentCards: currentCards});
  }
}
```

This will update the state only if the length of the `cards` array changes.

Comment: Thanks! My logic is a little different, but it awakens me to the fact that I have to study the React life cycle a lot.